# What phrase likely matches monkey and assistant?

Tags: phrase-requests

I came across this phrase a long time ago but have since forgotten it. It sounded something like *worm monkey* or *screw monkey*. it basically refers to someone whose only job is to help the mechanic or inventor do some of the easy work like assembling parts.

I've Googled several viarations of this phrase to see if I could stumble upon a match, but none of them seem to yield anything favourable.

Comment: It can be pretty much anything. The first word only helps to set the environment. *monkey* has all the semantic weight here. Grease monkeys came from early railroad and mining engines that needed frequent greasing, perhaps continuous in practice.

Comment: On a warship, powder monkeys ran about delivering the gunpowder to the cannons. They were usually youngsters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be thinking of a *grease monkey*, although this is simply a slang synonym for *mechanic* and doesn't have any implication of being an assistant.

### [grease monkey](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/grease-monkey)

*noun Slang.*
a mechanic, especially one who works on automobiles or airplanes.

Comment: As already suggested. But OP hasn't looked for collocates of 'monkey', which will rapidly give this.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Can you suggest any tools or methods to look for such collocates?

Comment: @Mitch The 'list of general references' on [meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available) is required reading! The Oxford Collocations Dictionary (OZDIC) is standard.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Help them out instead of cutting them off. You could have spent the same energy suggesting that dictionary. Also, just because it may appear in such a reference doesn't mean the OP has the means to judge which one is appropriate. I spent a lot of time collecting and editing parts of that gen ref page and this mention here is the first I've heard of the collocations dictionary.

Comment: Also, I just explored OZDIC and on first couple of uses it translates 'monkey' to 'money' in its search (ie I can't search for monkey) and then trying 'grease monkey' it returns nothing. So I can't really expect a newcomer to ELU to be able to navigate to meta, scan the entire gen ref page, realize that OZDIC is relevant, then spend whatever time it takes to use it well to find easily what you call standard.

Comment: @Mitch I've checked, and it doesn't have _grease monkey_; if OP had noted this, it would have validated the question. However, a quick search finds the compound / strong collocation at [Englishbyday ... 'monkey' idioms](https://englishbyday.com/monkey-idioms/). // The ethos of ELU is to build up a scholarly body addressing non-basic grammar, semantics, idioms .... It is not primarily to help with every question asked; questions are opportunities to build the database. There is a requirement that questions be accompanied by reasonable research. OZDIC is a standard resource.

Comment: ... Note also that while 'grease monkey' is probably the only possible 'reply', as Chappo says, it doesn't accurately address the question. Perhaps the monkey / organ-grinder pairing is in OP's mind. Perhaps not. // The newcomer has possibly been helped, and the question close-voted in accordance with regulations. Win-win.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 1) Help the newcomers 2) It's not 'standard'... help the oldcomers.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 'X monkey' would be a good answer that's not obvious. (I'm doing all sorts of searching and can't find anything but I have a good native speaker intuition about this (eg 'SurveyMonkey' is an example of analogy of a common pattern.) Help people out rather than shut them down because of 'rules'.

Comment: @Mitch 'survey monkey' wouldn't help many people other than OP, and might actually disadvantage / misinform some readers, thinking that it's a standard phrase. _These tissues are micro soft._